# Solidity shr opcode

Tags: solidity, assembly, opcode

What does this code mean?

```
sender := shr(96, calldataload(sub(calldatasize(), 20)))
```

Btw sender is an address variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `shr` function is used to extract variables from the calldata. The calldata is the `msg.data` you're passing to the contract with the function.

Imagine your calldata is this:

```
0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2eaabb2ee89221455302d9ffb5325689ff8f0c37b000000000000000009369ed80b93d665
```

When you do `shr(96, calldataload(0x00))` what you're doing is adding 12 bytes to the left of the calldata (pushing the calldata to the right).

The 96 from `shr(96)` is in bits, in bytes that's 96 / 8 = 12 bytes. Meaning you're adding 24 zeroes in front of the calldata (1 byte is 2 letters). So now calldata would look like this:

```
0x000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2eaabb2ee89221455302d9ffb5325689ff8f0c37b000000000000000009369ed80b93d665
```

Why is that important? Because you're storing the data into a variable called `sender := shr(96, ...)`.

Variables in assembly are all 32 bytes (64 characters).

Therefore the variable **cuts off everything after 32 bytes** (or 64 characters remember that 1 bytes is 2 letters). So the variable sender becomes:

`sender := 000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2`

Storing successfully the first address into sender.

So that's how you extract the first parameter of the calldata.

**That's it!**

I figured this all by playing around with assembly in remix and seeing how the zeroes are being added.

---

---

---

Here's more info. Imagine your calldata being this:

```
0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2eaabb2ee89221455302d9ffb5325689ff8f0c37b000000000000000009369ed80b93d665
```

Basically what it contains is all this data combined into one:

`0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2`

`eaabb2ee89221455302d9ffb5325689ff8f0c37b`

`000000000000000009369ed80b93d665`

Here's the breakdown:

1. First parameter is an `address` the length is 42 characters, 2 characters are 1 byte. Addresses in solidity are 40 characters long (0x14 hex). This will be important later on.
2. Second `address` (notice how the 0x at the start is removed because it's only purpose is to tell the compiler that the data you're sending is hexadecimal)
3. Third parameter is the number `663892645828089500` expressed in hexadecimal padded with zeroes so it has a length of 16 bytes which means it's a uint128.

All variables in assembly are 32 bytes (0x20 in hex) or 64 characters. Therefore addresses are represented with 24 zeroes in front of them, because addresses are 40 characters long, they need those extra 24 to have a length of 64 characters and become 32 bytes, which then becomes a valid address variable in assembly.

Numbers in assembly are expressed in hexadecimal because it allows you to store more data in less space. A uint256 is 32 bytes long or 64 characters. A uint128 is 16 bytes or 32 characters long. Once you convert the number to hex, you add zeroes to the left to make it a valid variable.

Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 9):

`shr(a, b)` shifts `b` right by `a` bits, so in this case it shifts the result of `calldataload` right by 96 bits. This code essentially takes the last 20 bytes from the calldata (a.k.a. `msg.data`) and removes the first 12 bytes (96 bits) from it to get a 20 byte address.

You can find all Yul (inline assembly) functions and what they do here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/yul.html#evm-dialect